# IOS indicator before change the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, delay, indicator

i have a collectionView, with 8 Items. One item is TableViewController, and downloading Images for cell BackgroundView.

When i just click on Item, the TableView appears 2-3 second later. (Sometimes 5sec., when bad connection). For this reason, the users will think the app is frozen.

I want to implement an indicator, which appears until the view is loaded.
When do i know the TableView is finished with downloading?

Because when i click the item, the code from "TableViewController" is running, but i see the collectionView, and after 3-4 sec it appears

Need help :/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not using **LazyLoding** for **Image downloading**. 
If you download image in **main Thread then application is stuck** until the image is not downloaded and display.

You can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for image downloading.

Here is the steps to implement into your application:

-Click on Zip tag and download the archive.

-Unarchive the file.

-You will find the "SDWebImage" folder.

-see that path and add this folder in your project. (don't forget to take copy of folder in your project instead of jusk linking).

Happy Coding :)