# My app is frozen and slow in iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm developing an app which loads data from server in a `UITableView` and each cell is customized.

The problem is when I run this app on my iPhone 4s it is slow and frozen, but it works in other devices without having frozen or slowing.
I have some images in my app used for cell background. How to solve this issue?

Why is is slow on iPhone 4s only?

Is there any way to solve this issue?

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
ThreadInfo *info=[_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

//HIDE EXTRA REPLYVIEW

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"replyview";

IXOutMessageCustomCell *cells = (IXOutMessageCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cells == nil) {
    cells = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IXOutMessageCustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    cells.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}


// if (cells.replyview.hidden == NO) {
cells.replyview.hidden = YES;

//}





if([info.isSystemMessage boolValue])
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SystemListCell";

    IXSystemMessageCustomCell *cell = (IXSystemMessageCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IXSystemMessageCustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        [cell.playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }

    [self configureSystemCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
else if([info.isPoll boolValue] || [info.isQuiz boolValue])
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier1 = @"pollCell";

    IXPollCustomCell *pollCell = (IXPollCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];


    if (pollCell == nil) {

        pollCell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IXPollCustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        pollCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;




    }

    if([info.pollType isEqualToString:@"Star"])
    {

        CGFloat cellFrameHeight = pollCell.frame.size.height;//changed
        CGFloat cellFrameWidth = pollCell.frame.size.width;//changed
        pollCell.starView.frame = CGRectMake(0, cellFrameHeight / 2 +40, cellFrameWidth, 73);


    }



    [self configurePollCell:pollCell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGRect dateRect=pollCell.dateLabel.frame;
    CGRect lineRect=pollCell.lineImageView.frame;
    CGRect visibilityRect=pollCell.visibilityButton.frame;

    if([info.pollType isEqualToString:@"Binary"])
    {
        CGFloat choiceFrameHeight=100;


        if (info.image !=nil) {
            dateRect.origin.y=pollCell.multiChoiceView.frame.origin.y+choiceFrameHeight+10+10+210;//edited by rsk
            lineRect.origin.y=178+100+60+10-1;
            visibilityRect.origin.y=pollCell.multiChoiceView.frame.origin.y+choiceFrameHeight+23+10+5+210;//edited by rsk

        }
        else {

            dateRect.origin.y=pollCell.multiChoiceView.frame.origin.y+choiceFrameHeight+10+10;
            lineRect.origin.y=178+100+60+10-1;
            visibilityRect.origin.y=pollCell.multiChoiceView.frame.origin.y+choiceFrameHeight+23+10+5;//edited by rsk
        }

    }
    else if([info.pollType isEqualToString:@"MultiChoice"])
    {
        NSMutableArray *optionList=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:info.pollOptions];

 //            CGFloat choiceFrameHeight=pollCell.multiChoiceView.frame.size.height;
        CGFloat choiceFrameHeight;

        if(optionList.count==3)
        {
            choiceFrameHeight=140+10+5;//edited by rsk
            lineRect.origin.y=178+140+70+6-1;

        }
        else if(optionList.count==4 )
        {
            choiceFrameHeight=190+5;//edited by rsk
            lineRect.origin.y=178+180+60+30-1;

        }
        else
        {
            choiceFrameHeight=220+20+5;//edited by rsk
            lineRect.origin.y=178+220+60+40-1;


        }
        dateRect.origin.y=pollCell.multiChoiceView.frame.origin.y-20+choiceFrameHeight+40;
        visibilityRect.origin.y=pollCell.multiChoiceView.frame.origin.y-20+choiceFrameHeight+55;        }

    else if([info.pollType isEqualToString:@"Star"])
    {
        if(info.image !=nil)
        {

            dateRect.origin.y=pollCell.starView.frame.origin.y+pollCell.starView.frame.size.height+10+210;//edited by rsk
            visibilityRect.origin.y=pollCell.starView.frame.origin.y+pollCell.starView.frame.size.height+20+5+210;//edited by rsk

        } else {
            dateRect.origin.y=pollCell.starView.frame.origin.y+pollCell.starView.frame.size.height+10;
            visibilityRect.origin.y=pollCell.starView.frame.origin.y+pollCell.starView.frame.size.height+20+5;//edited by rsk

        }

        lineRect.origin.y=178+75+60-1;
    }
    else
    {
        dateRect.origin.y=299-50;
        visibilityRect.origin.y=299-40+5;//edited by rsk

        lineRect.origin.y=299;
    }
    pollCell.dateLabel.frame=dateRect;

    //   pollCell.lineImageView.frame=lineRect;
    pollCell.lineImageView.hidden= YES;

    pollCell.visibilityButton.frame=visibilityRect;
    CGRect visibilityPopupRect=pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame;

    if(info.image !=nil){

        visibilityPopupRect.origin.y=visibilityRect.origin.y-visibilityPopupRect.size.height+210;//edited by rsk

    } else {

       visibilityPopupRect.origin.y=visibilityRect.origin.y-visibilityPopupRect.size.height;
    }


    pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame=visibilityPopupRect;
    pollCell.bgImageView.frame=pollCell.contentView.frame;



    if([info.pollType isEqualToString:@"Star"])     //Star
    {


      //  NSLog(@"STAR LOG %d",cellHeight);
      //  NSLog(@"STAR LOGss %f",pollCell.frame.size.height);
      //  NSLog(@"STAR FRAME HEIGHt %f",self.view.frame.size.height);

        float framesize = 0.8*self.view.frame.size.height;

        if(info.image !=nil)
        {

            if (info.threadMessage.length > 100){


                [pollCell.dateLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(pollCell.dateLabel.frame.origin.x, framesize-50+140+30, pollCell.dateLabel.frame.size.width, pollCell.dateLabel.frame.size.height)];

                [pollCell.visibilityButton setFrame:CGRectMake(pollCell.visibilityButton.frame.origin.x,5+framesize-40+140+30, pollCell.visibilityButton.frame.size.width, pollCell.visibilityButton.frame.size.height)];//edited by rsk

                [pollCell.visibilityPopupView setFrame:CGRectMake(pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame.origin.x, framesize-80+150+30, pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame.size.width, pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame.size.height)];



            } else {
                [pollCell.dateLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(pollCell.dateLabel.frame.origin.x, framesize-50+140+10, pollCell.dateLabel.frame.size.width, pollCell.dateLabel.frame.size.height)];

                [pollCell.visibilityButton setFrame:CGRectMake(pollCell.visibilityButton.frame.origin.x,5+framesize-40+140+10, pollCell.visibilityButton.frame.size.width, pollCell.visibilityButton.frame.size.height)];//edited by rsk

                [pollCell.visibilityPopupView setFrame:CGRectMake(pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame.origin.x, framesize-80+150+10, pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame.size.width, pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame.size.height)];

            }



            } else {

            [pollCell.dateLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(pollCell.dateLabel.frame.origin.x, framesize-50, pollCell.dateLabel.frame.size.width, pollCell.dateLabel.frame.size.height)];

            [pollCell.visibilityButton setFrame:CGRectMake(pollCell.visibilityButton.frame.origin.x,5+framesize-40, pollCell.visibilityButton.frame.size.width, pollCell.visibilityButton.frame.size.height)];//edited by rsk

            [pollCell.visibilityPopupView setFrame:CGRectMake(pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame.origin.x, framesize-80, pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame.size.width, pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame.size.height)];

        }

    }






    if([info.pollType isEqualToString:@"MultiChoice"] || [info.pollType isEqualToString:@"Binary"] )
    {
        NSMutableArray *optionList=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:info.pollOptions];

        if((optionList.count==5) || (optionList.count==10) ) {
            if(info.image !=nil){

                CGRect adjustVisibility = visibilityRect;
                adjustVisibility.origin.y -= 20;
                pollCell.visibilityButton.frame=adjustVisibility;
                CGRect adjustDate = dateRect;
                adjustDate.origin.y -= 20;
                pollCell.dateLabel.frame=adjustDate;
                visibilityPopupRect.origin.y=visibilityRect.origin.y-visibilityPopupRect.size.height-30;
                pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame=visibilityPopupRect;

            }

            NSLog(@"nothing");
        } else {


            float framesize = 0.8*self.view.frame.size.height;

            if (info.image != nil) {

                 if([info.pollType isEqualToString:@"Binary"])
                 {
                    float framesize = 0.8*self.view.frame.size.height;
                    [pollCell.dateLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(pollCell.dateLabel.frame.origin.x, framesize-40+177, pollCell.dateLabel.frame.size.width, pollCell.dateLabel.frame.size.height)];

                    [pollCell.visibilityButton setFrame:CGRectMake(pollCell.visibilityButton.frame.origin.x,5+framesize-30+177, pollCell.visibilityButton.frame.size.width, pollCell.visibilityButton.frame.size.height)];//edited by rsk

                    [pollCell.visibilityPopupView setFrame:CGRectMake(pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame.origin.x, framesize-70+187, pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame.size.width, pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame.size.height)];
                 } else {


                     [pollCell.dateLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(pollCell.dateLabel.frame.origin.x, framesize-40+200, pollCell.dateLabel.frame.size.width, pollCell.dateLabel.frame.size.height)];

                     [pollCell.visibilityButton setFrame:CGRectMake(pollCell.visibilityButton.frame.origin.x,5+framesize-30+200, pollCell.visibilityButton.frame.size.width, pollCell.visibilityButton.frame.size.height)];//edited by rsk

                     [pollCell.visibilityPopupView setFrame:CGRectMake(pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame.origin.x, framesize-70+210, pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame.size.width, pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame.size.height)];
                 }

            } else {


                [pollCell.dateLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(pollCell.dateLabel.frame.origin.x, framesize-40, pollCell.dateLabel.frame.size.width, pollCell.dateLabel.frame.size.height)];

                [pollCell.visibilityButton setFrame:CGRectMake(pollCell.visibilityButton.frame.origin.x,5+framesize-30, pollCell.visibilityButton.frame.size.width, pollCell.visibilityButton.frame.size.height)];//edited by rsk

                [pollCell.visibilityPopupView setFrame:CGRectMake(pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame.origin.x, framesize-70, pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame.size.width, pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame.size.height)];






            }

                          //  NSLog(@"framee size %f", self.view.frame.size.height);



        if (self.view.frame.size.height <= 480 && (optionList.count ==4 || optionList.count == 8) )
            {
                if([info.pollType isEqualToString:@"Binary"] && optionList.count ==4){

                }else {

                    if (optionList.count == 8) {
                        dateRect.origin.y = dateRect.origin.y-50;
                        visibilityRect.origin.y = visibilityRect.origin.y-50;

                        pollCell.dateLabel.frame=dateRect;
                        pollCell.visibilityButton.frame=visibilityRect;
                        visibilityPopupRect.origin.y=visibilityRect.origin.y-visibilityPopupRect.size.height;
                        pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame=visibilityPopupRect;

                    } else {

                        if (info.image !=nil) {
                            CGRect adjustDate = dateRect;
                            adjustDate.origin.y -= 28;
                            pollCell.dateLabel.frame=adjustDate;
                            CGRect adjustVisibility = visibilityRect;
                            adjustVisibility.origin.y -= 28;
                            pollCell.visibilityButton.frame=adjustVisibility;
                            visibilityPopupRect.origin.y=visibilityRect.origin.y-visibilityPopupRect.size.height-38;
                            pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame=visibilityPopupRect;

                        } else {
                            pollCell.dateLabel.frame=dateRect;
                            pollCell.visibilityButton.frame=visibilityRect;
                            visibilityPopupRect.origin.y=visibilityRect.origin.y-visibilityPopupRect.size.height;
                            pollCell.visibilityPopupView.frame=visibilityPopupRect;

                        }

                    }
                }
            }


                }

            }



    return pollCell;


}
else if([info.isSender boolValue ]|| [info.isRequester boolValue]|| [info.isReceiver boolValue] || [info.isProvider boolValue])
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"AppListCell";



    IXOutMessageCustomCell *cell = (IXOutMessageCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];



    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IXOutMessageCustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        //cell._mAskedButton.hidden=YES;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        [cell.tapButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showPopup:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    if (cell.replyview.hidden == NO) {
        cell.replyview.hidden = YES;

    }


    if ([info.isRequester boolValue]) {

        NSNumber *count = info.responseCount;

        NSInteger value = [count integerValue];

        for (int i =0; i<value; i++) {
            [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

        }

    } else {
        [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    if([info.isSender boolValue] || [info.isRequester boolValue] || [info.isProvider boolValue])
    {
        CGRect dateFrame=cell.dateLabel.frame;
        dateFrame.origin.x=15;
        cell.dateLabel.frame=dateFrame;
        cell.dateLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    }
    else
    {
        CGRect dateFrame=cell.dateLabel.frame;
        dateFrame.origin.x=48;
        cell.dateLabel.frame=dateFrame;
        cell.dateLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    }
    [cell.showTypeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showTypePopUp_Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];//edited by rsk
    return cell;

}
else
{
    return nil;
}

 }
```

Comment: Is it relatively slow on other devices too or not at all?

Comment: The other devices that you run your code on, which devices are those? iphone5, iphone6?

Comment: Also, are you using dequeReusableCell? Share some of the code here as well if you can.

Comment: What have you done to track down the source of the issue? Have you used Instruments and carried out any measurements? Post the output.

Comment: iphone 5, iphone 6, ipad mini , etc.. are working fine

Comment: I didn't get the issue, i don't know the reason of the issue,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not related to any device, it related how can you download image.

I think you are not downloading image in the background. Please check [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29231705/2013229)

Comment: I'am not downloading any images, It is with my project folder.

Comment: How can you set image into UIImageView? Issue is related to show the image.

Comment: No, I was used images but for now i just removed those images from project and now using colors instead of that, And still getting frozen.